# graph api array comments and updates

Tags: arrays, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering how i would display the comments story tags with the following array....

```
{  "data": [    {     
 "id": "1364392319_4278554326462",       
"from": {       
"name": "Dave Morin",        
"id": "1364392319"      },       
"story": "Dave Morin was tagged in Shae Rachael Garton's album Mobile Uploads.",      
"story_tags": {       
"0": [          {            
"id": 1364392319,             
"name": "Dave Morin",            
"offset": 0,             
"length": 10,             
"type": "user"          }        ],         
"25": [          {            
"id": 100000204772261,             
"name": "Shae Rachael Garton",            
"offset": 25,            
"length": 19,             "type": "user"          }        ]      },
```

Obviously its layed out better but thats the best i could grab :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand your question, but it sounds like you're asking how to best use the information in the `story_tags` parameter to recreate the way Facebook highlights the username when such a post is displayed on Facebook.com?

It would help to know what code are you using and what the problem is if you want specific code examples, because it looks like you have the data you need there, but:

- For each entry in the `story_tags` array:

  - `id` is the User or Page ID linked to by this tag
  - `name` is the name of that object
  - `offset` is the first character in the original message which should be highlighted/linked (i.e In this case, the original message is the `story` on the next level out` )
  - `length` is the number of characters to be highlighted/linked
  - `type` is the type of object linked in the tag

So for the example there:

Dave Morin was tagged in Shae Rachael Garton's album Mobile Uploads.

Tagging at offset 0 for 10 characters and offset 25 for 19 would highlight it like this:

**Dave Morin** was tagged in **Shae Rachael Garton**'s album Mobile Uploads.

With the first link linking to Dave's profile and the second to Shae's

Comment: What im trying to do is display it via PHP.

Comment: If you're having a specific problem update your question and i'll try to answer, but i think what i have there is enough info, at the most basic level, take the `offset` for the point to put the tag in, and stick an '<a href="[link to profile on facebook]">' before it, and a '</a>' after the `length` of the tag, for the next tags do the same, but increase your offset by the number of characters you inserted when adding the `<a ...></a> tags`